# Why can I say,'Why do you like her so much?' but not, 'Why do you like her very much?'

Tags: meaning-in-context, questions, so-vs-very

Why can I say,'Why do you like her **so much**?' but not, 'Why do you like her **very much**?'

My answer is:
 'Why' is evaluative and forces you to make (or consider) a comparison. Very cannot be used in comparative constructs.

A friend of mine raised the point:
 That 'very' seems to work in the negative form. For example: "Why don't you like her very much?"

Comment: For one, *very much* does not mean 'more than much'.

Comment: What makes you think you think "but not, 'Why do you like her very much?'"

Comment: Hi Kris, agreed. Is the negative interrogative  form of 'very much' then a colloquialism? The negative 'very much' form seems to be asking about the degree to which someone is liked, but this cannot be asked in a positive form. The closest we have is 'so much' which is forcing you, in this case, to consider how much you like her compared to others. Is this correct?

Comment: From usage, I do not see much difference between *so much* and *very much* to the extent that they can be used in the sense each conveys. Any evidence that *very much* cannot be used as in your example?

Comment: _What makes you think you think "but not, 'Why do you like her very much?'"_ It was my understanding that a 'Why' questions force you to consider between options - as you say: very much does not mean 'more than much' - very much is considering the level to which one likes (gradability).

Comment: I can't find any academic references on this exact problem, thus my question. However, while running a search for some supporting evidence I did discover that if I ran a Boolean search for _Why, 'so much' OR why, 'very much'_ almost all positive Why-interrogative statements used 'so much' and almost all negative Why-interrogative statements used 'very much.'This was particularly prevalent when searching Google Scholar. This also suggest that my 'comparative' conclusion was wrong. Unfortunately this does not help me shed any light on why one is used and not the other. Any thoughts?

Comment: There does seem to be a large degree of idiosyncrasy here. I think I can remember when 'I like him / her very much' sounded distinctly cheesy, but it's probably overtaken 'I like him / her a lot' nowadays. 'Do you like him very much?' is probably used a lot less often than 'Do you like him a lot?' or 'Do you _really like_ him?' (contrast 'Do you _really_ like him?'!) And when we consider the acceptability of 'Why do you like her so very much?', we see another layer of complication. We wouldn't use other highly-intensifying / intensified expressions either: ??Why do you admire her enormously?

Comment: "I don't like her very much" is not the opposite of "I like her very much". So there are too possible meanings of "very much", one in negative statements and one in positive statements.  Only the negative one works in questions. It's possible that if both of these meanings were allowed in questions, the ambiguity would be too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

"Why do you like her so much?" is saying "why do you like her *as much as you do, which is a lot*?" ("So much".)

"Why don't you like her very much?" has the same meaning as saying "Why don't you like her *much*?" — the *very* just adds a little more politeness. 
(Again, it could be written "Why don't you like her?" — even less polite). The meaning *could* be you like her a bit (but not very much), and because the bit is ambiguous it's not as blunt and potentially destructive as saying "you dislike her". So with the extra politeness the person not liking the other person might be more tempted to open up and tell all (because they are shielded from controversy).

In English there is also the phrase "very much so" in answer to a question (although more used by middle-aged and older people than 20-year-olds), meaning "very much yes".

But in general, "very much" sounds bad to the English ear, normally "so much" or "as much as *_*_" is more appropriate. To me "very much" sounds slightly coloquial, language for social use. I don't think the 'rules' of English are entirely logical though — it's more habit and culture.

Comment: A: I like her very much! B: Why do you like her very much?

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան:  I think it more common that it would be:   A: I like her very much!  B: Why do you like her so much?    // It's not that your version of B is incorrect, it's just off to my ear, as user37294 pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

'So much' implies that the interrogator is aware of the other person's level of affinity to her.

'Very much' would imply that the interrogator is aware of the affinity, but not the level of affinity. Therefore, the question would be incomplete without first asking how much the person actually likes her. Once that level is established with an answer, it can be referenced by using a conjunction like 'so'.

Alternatively, you can also say 'Why do you like her that much?', 'that' being a restrictive relative clause in this case.